# php request youtube video is not working

Tags: php, flash, video, youtube, jwplayer

what is wrong to this code?

```
header('Content-type: application/x-shockwave-flash');
$video_id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$content = readfile("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$video_id");
echo $content;
```

Why this code is not working? How should look the code?

---

i've edited like this:

```
header('Content-type: application/x-shockwave-flash');
$video_id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$content = readfile("http://www.youtube.com/v/$video_id");
echo $content;
```

and if i get http://localhost/media.php?id=pkyRRD9f0ts in browser it works but if i add it in jwplayer it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're pulling the entire webpage as you would view it in a browser, not just the video file (youtube specifically doesn't allow that).

Try echoing an embed html tag instead.

```
echo <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$video_id">;
```

Comment: the reason of what? readfile() goes and gets the file (entire webpage, html, css, js and all). but you don't want that, you want only the video which youtube does not allow.

Comment: i'm sorry, i can't help you with jwplayer, i've never used it before.